# show a marker on a Google maps map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I build this script that initializes a map for a specific point:

Note: `(x, y)` are latitude-longitude coordinates.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var businessMap;

        function showBusinessMap(x, y) {
            var xops = 
            {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)
            }

            var chosenPoint = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
            });

            businessMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("businessMap"), xops);

            chosenPoint.setMap(businessMap);
            chosenPoint.setVisible(true);


        }
</script>
```

It works good , but no marker is shown on the map.

I also have this jQuery function that resizes the map:

```
            $('#showMap').on('shown', function() {
                google.maps.event.trigger(businessMap, "resize");
            });
```

How can I make the marker `chosenPoint` to be shown?

If I missed any info, please let me know and I'll add it.

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

```
    var businessMap;

    function showBusinessMap(x, y) {
        var xops = 
        {
            zoom: 15,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)
        }

        businessMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("businessMap"), xops);

        var chosenPoint = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
            map: businessMap
        });
    }
```

Still doesn't work.

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  I suspect it works just fine and your map div doesn't have a size (at least it works for me on a local copy).

Comment: http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_businessMap.html

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
You need to add your created `chosenPoint` to the map.

From the Google Maps API,

```
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882,131.044922);
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatlng
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

// To add the marker to the map, use the 'map' property
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title:"Hello World!"
});
```

So, in your case, create the map object first, then the marker object second, and include `map: businessMap` in the options for the marker, much like the example above.

[Look here for more information.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

Answer (score 0):

```
 var address = "Address, City, ProvinceOrState, Country"; 

 geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         //console.log("GeocoderStatus.OK  :  " + results[0].geometry.location);
         var mapOptions = {
             zoom: 8,
             center: results[0].geometry.location,
             mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
         }
         //load the map
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);

         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: results[0].geometry.location
         });

     } //if
     else { console.log("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status); }
 })
```

The following section is the part that adds the "Marker"

```
         var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
             map: map,
             position: results[0].geometry.location
         });
```

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, here's a simple example base on your code that works.  I imagine your problem is caused by something outside of what you're showing us.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        var businessMap;

        function showBusinessMap(x, y) {

            var xops = {
                zoom: 15,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y)
            };
            var businessMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("businessMap"),
            xops);

            var chosenPoint = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(x, y),
                map: businessMap
            });

        }

        function initialize() {
            showBusinessMap(-34.397, 150.644);
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

</script>
```